# loading application on blackberry playbook simulator encountered an error

Tags: vmware, blackberry-playbook, qnx

I developed an application in BlackBerry playbook native sdk using QNX. I try to test it on simulator(running in vmware) an error occurred like `"'Downloading and starting the application...' has encoundered a problem"`. The screenshot attached below[image]

**UPDATE**

I tested it on developer alpha device and woks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run an application built using the BlackBerry 10 NDK on a BlackBerry PlayBook running PlayBook OS 2.1.0.  Typically, applications built in the NDK are forwards compatible, but not backwards compatible.

You'll need to use the version 2.x BlackBerry NDK to build the application for your PlayBook running 2.1.0.